# What is the alternative to Komodo IDE, and Komodo Edit on Windows?

Tags: windows-7, text-editors

What is the alternative editor that I could use instead of Komodo IDE / Komodo Edit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a programmer-centric text editor it's hard to go wrong with [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/).  [Notepad2](http://www.flos-freeware.ch/notepad2.html) is also popular.

For a more developed IDE I would look at the [Express Editions of Visual Studio](http://www.microsoft.com/express/).
There's also [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/) and [Netbeans](http://netbeans.org/).

Answer (score 1):

Try the minimalist [Textpad](http://www.textpad.com/). Actually used it for a few years before moving on to Komodo (nothing beats Komodo for dynamic languages and regex; I use it for Perl and Python). Textpad is lightweight and speedy plus a fully functional trial copy is available. (if you can stand the nag screens). I paid. It also has a very cool and useful block select mode. IMHO, it seems like taking a step backwards moving away from Komodo. Visual Studio is decent but overkill for most tasks. Eclipse fine, but seem a little bit too Java centric for my taste.

[image: Textpad]